# How to read/write UNIX sockets the right way?

Tags: c++, sockets, unix

I want to implement the functionality of this bash-command that read/write to a **UNIX socket**:

```
echo „READ <a command>“ | nc -U /tmp/socket
```

this command produces the following output:

```
Click::ControlSocket/1.3
200 Read handler 'debug_handler.ping' OK
DATA 0
```

My current c/c++ implementation looks something like this:

myprogram.hh

```
class Myprogram {
public:
    Myprogram(int argc, char** argv);
    ~Myprogram() { };   
private:
    foo();
    int sockfd;
    int len;
    sockaddr_un address;
};
```

myprogram.cc

```
Myprogram::foo() {
    sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(address.sun_path, "/tmp/socket");
    len = sizeof(address);

    if(connect(sockfd, (sockaddr*)&address, len) == -1)
        return;

    std::string args = "READ <a command>";

    if (write(sockfd, args.c_str(), sizeof(args.c_str())) == -1){
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }   

    int n;
    char ret_value[200];
    do {
        n = read(sockfd, ret_value, 200);
        std::cout << std::string(ret_value) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "n=" << std::to_string(n) << std::endl;
        *ret_value+= n;
    } while (n > 0);

    close(sockfd);
}
```

I only get this output:

```
Click::ControlSocket/1.3
n=26
```

the next read() call doesn‘t return and the program waits.
I have tried a lot to read the socket, all with the same result,
so it would be great if someone could give me a hint what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `sizeof(args.c_str())` is 4 or 8.

Comment: `sizeof(args.c_str())` should be `args.size()`.

Comment: C/C++ isn't a language. If you think `class` is a keyword, you're writing C++.

Comment: Your ret_value buffer is 200 bytes long, you read 200 bytes of data into it. Where will the nul-terminator come from and/or be stored?

Comment: You don't need a null terminator if you write the buffer to `cout` in a manner that does not rely on a null terminator in the first place. `recv()` returns how many bytes were actually read.  `cout` has a `write()` method that takes a `char*` buffer and a count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::string args = "READ <a command>";
```

the server is waiting for a newline (echo adds one by default), so:

```
std::string args = "READ <a command>\n";
```

Also

```
char ret_value[200];
do {
    n = read(sockfd, ret_value, 200);
```

should be more like

```
const size_t buflen = 200;
char ret_value[buflen+1];
do {
    n = read(sockfd, ret_value, buflen);
    if (n < 0)
      // error
    else
      ret_value[n] = 0;
```

and this line

```
    *ret_value+= n;
```

seems unclear - you're incrementing the first byte of ret_value by n for what reason?

Comment: I had also sizeof(args.c_str()) change to args.size() like @πάνταῥεῖ said. But all hints were helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try something more like this:

```
Myprogram::foo() {
    sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(address.sun_path, "/tmp/socket");

    if (connect(sockfd, (sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address)) == -1) {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        close(sockfd);
        return;
    }

    std::string args = "READ <a command>\n";
    if (write(sockfd, args.c_str(), args.size())) == -1) {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        close(sockfd);
        return;
    }   

    int n;
    char ret_value[200];
    do {
        n = read(sockfd, ret_value, sizeof(ret_value));
        if (n < 0) {
            std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        if (n == 0) {
            break;
        }

        std::cout.write(ret_value, n) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "n=" << n << std::endl;
    } while (true);

    close(sockfd);
}
```

Of course, if you really want the output to appear just like the original than don't add your own characters to `cout` (except maybe in case of an error):

```
int n;
char ret_value[200];
do {
    n = read(sockfd, ret_value, sizeof(ret_value));
    if (n < 0) {
        //std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    if (n == 0) {
        break;
    }

    std::cout.write(ret_value, n);
} while (true);
```

Comment: This is a great solution, thanks. But a problem that still exists, if all lines have been read the read-function does not return and the program waits.